# LINUX/BASH - rc.local doesn't open terminal through bashscript after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix

I have been trying to run a bashscript when my VM reboots. I've used /etc/rc.local for this & it executes perfectly. However, a specific line that tells the script to automatically open the terminal & run a bashscript doesnt execute.

**rc.local code -- ( code to be executed when rebooted -- works good)**

```
#!/bin/bash -e
bash /folder/bootcode.sh 
exit 0
```

**bootcode.sh code -- ( executes only line 1 & not line 2)**

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
touch /datadrive/filemadewhenrebooted.txt  # --- **(LINE 1) this line executes perfectly** ---
x-terminal-emulator -e sudo bash /folder/myscript.sh  # --- **(LINE 2) this line does not work** ---
```

Can anyone help me out please? I've tried giving a delay of 30 seconds using the sleep command, so that the VM takes time to settle up after the reboot. But, that doesn't seem to work as well. The file "filemadewhenrebooted.txt" gets created immediately as if the script doesn't recognize the sleep command.

```
  #! /usr/bin/bash
    sleep 30 # --- doesn't recognize this line ---
    touch /datadrive/filemadewhenrebooted.txt  # --- **(LINE 1) this line executes perfectly** ---
    x-terminal-emulator -e sudo bash /folder/myscript.sh  # --- **(LINE 2) this line does not work** ---
```

Comment: You need the delay, but why do you use sudo? That is also a problem. You are already root, but root cannot access your graphic environment.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the script doesn't seem to recognize the delay. It immediately creates the text file "filemadewhenrebooted.txt" after the reboot. Additionally, removing the sudo doesnt change anything. Also, are you saying that the bashscript will not be able to open the terminal after reboot since it cannot access the graphic environment?

Comment: I have no idea on what are you doing. why running `x-terminal-emulator`? Do you need a graphical console? But so, why not running the script by putting on startup scripts of your graphiucal environment? And if you need to run to one user (and not graphical env), just usr `crontab` with the *time* set to `@reboot` (again: probably you must do a wait: cronttab are executed before many other services are run

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I need the `x-terminal-emulator` since i am using the `watch` command to monitor a directory & need the results to be shown on the terminal. The scripts will be run through the graphical environment itself, but this comes in action only when my virtual machine reboots due to unexpected conditions. Hence, the VM should be able to re-run these scripts after reboot.

Comment: Maybe [gnome-session-properties](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/gnome-session-properties.1.html)

Comment: Joining @Bodo. `rc.local` doesn't run in a context where it can launch a terminal. I assume `DISPLAY` env var is probably not set, and xauth is probably not set up to allow graphical commands from `rc.local`).

Answer (score 0):

**I finally found an answer.**

I've realized that, using `rc.local` is not ideal as it might be running too soon for the flash disk to be mounted. Hence, use this instead -->

1. On your terminal, navigate to `.config/autostart` directory. `.config/autostart` may be in your home directory:

```
    cd ~/.config/autostart
```

2. Open the (new) `gnome-terminal.desktop` file with your favourite text editor.

```
    vi gnome-terminal.desktop
```

3. Paste the following code in the file. Edit the gnome-terminal.desktop file and change the line that goes `Exec=gnome-terminal` to `Exec=gnome-terminal --command "path/to/your/shell/script"`

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Exec=gnome-terminal
    Hidden=false
    NoDisplay=false
    X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
    Name[en_NG]=Terminal
    Name=Terminal
    Comment[en_NG]=Start Terminal On Startup
    Comment=Start Terminal On Startup
```

4. Save & exit `:wq`